# Using merge modules and InstallShield to install SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, installshield, merge-module

How can I use merge modules and InstallShield to install SQL Server 2008 on the client system?

Comment: SQL server cannot be installed as a merge module.

Answer (score 0):

Installing SQL server via concurrent installs and/or merge modules hasn't been supported in a very long time.  The slammer worm back in 2003 combined with concurrent MSDE installations proved to be a very, very big problem.

You don't mention the InstallShield project type you are using but you probably want to look at Setup Prerequistes.